# Remember the last expanded property in QGIS Print Layout

Tags: qgis, print-composer

While working with QGIS Print Layout, I usually set a property for an item (for example, "Position and Size" for "Map" item), then select another item and set a property. After that, when I select the previous item, all properties (I mean all collapsible groupboxes) are reset as in the animation and I have to scroll down again.

[image]

Is there a way to keep it in last and expanded position for the selected item?